how to jump to a href hash tag location in a large Qt/QML text item with RichText textFormat
I use Qt/QML Text Item to render a large standalone HTML page with some inner href hash links. and the container height is less than its content height. Everything works fine; I can click the link and see the console log, but I cannot jump the text item's visual position to the href tag position. please help.
The y property of the text item in the container should have been updated when I clicked the href link.
To simplify my question, let me give a minimal reproducible example here.
import QtQuick

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id:container
        height: root.height*.95
        width: root.width*.8
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Text {
            id: label
            width: container.width
            textFormat: Text.RichText
            wrapMode:Text.WordWrap

            onLinkActivated: function(link){
                console.log(link)
            }
            TapHandler {
                onTapped:function(eventPoint, button){
                    ani.running = !ani.running
                }
            }
            SequentialAnimation on y {
                id: ani
                loops: Animation.Infinite
                running: true
                PropertyAnimation { to: -label.contentHeight/100;duration: 3000 }
                PropertyAnimation { to: 0 ;duration: 3000}
            }
        }
    }
    function makeRequest()
    {
        var doc = new XMLHttpRequest();
        label.text = "";
        doc.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (doc.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                label.text = doc.responseText;
            }
        }
        doc.open("GET", "https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html");
        doc.send();
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        // label.text = backEnd.loadFile("C:/ebook/GNU MPFR 4.2.1.htm")
        makeRequest()
    }
}

and the HTML file can be manually downloaded from the URL link.  Now I want to click the blue link, expecting the text item to scroll itself to the exact tag location.


The Text component lacks the ability to retrieve the coordinates of a specified text position. However, you can use TextEdit, which includes a positionToRectangle method that returns a QRect for the given text position.
The challenge is that the text position must correspond to plain text, excluding any HTML or XML tags. Therefore, you need to locate the position of the target tag within the formatted text and then map that position to the plain text in the TextEdit. Since there is no built-in function to accomplish this, I created a helper component to determine the position of the target tag within the plain text.
* Another point I forgot to mention is that the <h1 id="h1">h1</h1> will be converted to <h1><a name="h1"></a> after the TextEdit initialization. Therefore, the search should be for the <a name="${link}"></a>.
ScrollView {
    id: scrollView
    contentWidth: width
    contentHeight: textedit.implicitHeight

    function textgen() {
        return `Table of content:<ul id="top"><li><a href="#h1">h1</a></li><li>
            <a href="#h2">h2</a></li><li><a href="#h3">h3</a></li><li><a href="#h4">h4</a></li></ul>
            <h1 id="h1">h1<sub><a href="#top">top</a></sub></h1>${'sss '.repeat(200)}
            <h1 id="h2">h2<sub><a href="#top">top</a></sub></h1>${'sss '.repeat(200)}
            <h1 id="h3">h3<sub><a href="#top">top</a></sub></h1>${'sss '.repeat(200)}
            <h1 id="h4">h4<sub><a href="#top">top</a></sub></h1>${'sss '.repeat(200)}`;
    }

    NumberAnimation {
        id: animateScroll

        target: scrollView.ScrollBar.vertical
        property: 'position'
        duration: 1000
        easing.type: Easing.InOutCubic
    }

    TextEdit {
        id: textedit

        property TextEdit helper: TextEdit { textFormat: Text.RichText }

        width: root.width
        text: scrollView.textgen()
        readOnly: true
        wrapMode:Text.WordWrap
        textFormat: Text.RichText
        selectByMouse: false
        
        HoverHandler { cursorShape: textedit.hoveredLink ? Qt.PointingHandCursor : Qt.ArrowCursor }
        
        onLinkActivated: link => {
            if(link.startsWith('#')) {
                let idx = text.match(`<a name="${link.slice(1)}"></a>`)?.index ?? -1;

                if(idx !== -1) {
                    // Copying the first slice from the beginning to the target index into the helper TextEdit
                    helper.text = text.slice(0, idx);
                    // The `helper.length` will represent the target position within the plain text.
                    const rect = positionToRectangle(helper.length);

                    animateScroll.to = rect.y/textedit.height;
                    animateScroll.restart();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Thanks for the answer.  1) when the rendering content is large, TextEdit/TextArea seems to go blank as I scroll backward, but Text/Label is fine. 2) can you share your helper component

@waynewang unfortunately, the rendering issue originates from TextEdit itself, and I haven't found a solution for it. The challenge with this problem is that it's impossible to determine the text coordinates within the Label/Text component. However, one option is to keep TextEdit invisible and use a different Text component for visual context. This approach may slow down the application, so I'm uncertain if it's a good idea, especially since it also duplicates the entire document. Regarding the second part, the term helper refers to the TextEdit helper section of the code.

@waynewang After some investigation, I discovered that TextEdit has issues with rendering tables, which prevents it from displaying documents correctly. I also tested a large document (1,000,000 characters) and found that it rendered without any problems. Therefore, it's best to avoid using tables or to find a workaround by replacing the original text before opening it in TextEdit.

thank you again, you are very accommodating. I didn't notice TextEdit helper. I tried your code, and that's fine for your test content, but not fit with most of my cases.  I found that TextEdit RichText only supports a subset of HTML 4 markup. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/richtext-html-subset.html, that's sad.
